# Is there a way to reduce the number of TinyMCE files and folders?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I'm trying to incorprate TinyMCE into my ASP.NET MVC project, and tiny_mce folder I include right now has 248 Files, 104 Folders.  I'm using only its basic functionality and themes.

Is there a way to reduce the number of files and folders for easier deployment?  Or what files and folders could I safely delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use their customizer to only include the plugins that you want which should knock it down a little:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download/custom_package.php

You could also look at PunyMCE which is a lite-weight version of TinyMCE:

http://www.moxieforge.net/overview.php?project_id=9&category_id=5